# Is there a way to count when a variable appears with (and without) another in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count in Excel how many times "A" appears with (and then without) "C" horizontally when they are not in the same location every time. Does anyone know an Excel formula that would work? Here is an example of my data.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | E |
| A | B | C | D | F |
| E | G | F | H | L |
| E | B | C | H | F |
| A | I | J | K | H |

Thanks!

Comment: What are you expected results?

Comment: Just looking to see how many times A appears with C when they are in the same horizontal line. In this example we should see 2 as the correct answer even though A and C are here 3 times each.

Comment: Right, I put an answer down. However, you found a working answer yet by ScottCraner. Make sure to accept it as such by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of rows that have both `A` and `C`, assuming that each can only be in the row one time each:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT((A1:E5="A")+(A1:E5="C"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E5)^0))>1))
```

This may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode on older versions.

To get the total without we add `COUNTIF(A1:E5,"A")` and sutract the formula above:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:E5,"A")-SUM(--(MMULT((A1:E5="A")+(A1:E5="C"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E5)^0))>1))
```

Same caveat about Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

---

If the values can be present multiple times per row then we need to do:

```
=SUM(--((MMULT(--(A1:E5="A"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E5)^0))>0)+(MMULT(--(A1:E5="C"),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:E5)^0))>0)>1))
```

Again Older versions need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, chances are you won't have access yet to the following functions. But this could be a nice usecase for [`BYROW()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb):

[image]

Formula in `I1` to count rows with 'A' **and** 'C':

```
=SUM(BYROW(A1:E5,LAMBDA(x,--(COUNTIF(x,"A")*COUNTIF(x,"C")))))
```

Or:

```
=SUM(--BYROW(A1:E5,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(UNIQUE(x)={"A","C"}))=2)))
```

---

Formula in `I2` to count rows with 'A' **but without** 'C':

```
=SUM(BYROW(A1:E5,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(x,"A")*(COUNTIF(x,"C")=0))))
```